# How to use a TFRecord file for batch prediction on GCP AI Platform?

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord, google-ai-platform

TL;DR
How does Google Cloud AI Platform unpack `TFRecord` files when doing batch predictions?

I have deployed a trained Keras model to Google Cloud AI Platform, but I'm having trouble with the file format for batch predictions. For training I'm using a `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` to read a list of `TFRecord` like the following which all works fine.

```
def unpack_tfrecord(record):
    parsed = tf.io.parse_example(record, {
        'chunk': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([128, 2, 3], tf.float32),  # Input
        'class': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([2], tf.int64),            # One-hot classification (binary)
    })

    return (parsed['chunk'], parsed['class'])

files = [str(p) for p in training_chunks_path.glob('*.tfrecord')]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files).batch(32).map(unpack_tfrecord)
model.fit(x=dataset, epochs=train_epochs)
tf.saved_model.save(model, model_save_path)
```

I upload the saved model to Cloud Storage and create a new model in AI Platform. AI Platform documentation states that "Batch with gcloud tool [supports] Text file with JSON instance strings or TFRecord file (may be compressed)" (https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/overview#prediction_input_data). But when I provide a TFRecord file i get the error:

```
("'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 1: invalid start byte", 8)
```

My TFRecord file contains a bunch of Protobuf encoded `tf.train.Example`. I'm not providing the `unpack_tfrecord` function to AI Platform, so I guess it makes sense that it can not unpack it properly, but I have node idea where to go from here. I'm not interested in using the JSON format as the data is too large.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same wonder. GCP / AI Platform documentation and examples are so frustrating.

Comment: I ended up using json as input. I'll try to run an experiment with tfrecord again to see if I can get it to work now.

Comment: Im thinking a custom prediction function is a (only?) way.

Comment: Did you find any other solution? I used a subclass model so that it is not possible to use the function model_to_estimator. Any ideas?

Comment: We ended up dropping AI Platform altogether and are now running TF in a container on Cloud Run. We ran into so many problems with AI Platform that it was not worth it. Now everything runs smoothly and cost effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way of going about this but for TF 2.x you can do something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_serving_input_fn():
    # your feature spec
    feature_spec = {
        'chunk': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([128, 2, 3], tf.float32),  
        'class': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([2], tf.int64),
    }

    serialized_tf_examples = tf.keras.Input(
        shape=[], name='input_example_tensor', dtype=tf.string)

    examples = tf.io.parse_example(serialized_tf_examples, feature_spec)

    # any processing 
    processed_chunks = tf.map_fn(
        <PROCESSING_FN>, 
        examples['chunk'], # ?
        dtype=tf.float32)

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(
        features={<MODEL_FIRST_LAYER_NAME>: processed_chunks},
        receiver_tensors={"input_example_tensor": serialized_tf_examples}
    )


estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
    keras_model=model,
    model_dir=<ESTIMATOR_SAVE_DIR>)

estimator.export_saved_model(
    export_dir_base=<WORKING_DIR>,
    serving_input_receiver_fn=make_serving_input_fn)
```